# Запуск скрипта из приложения на Си и получение ответа

Tags: c, cmd, execute

Добрый день, необходимо запустить python-скрипт, который отправляет данные print'ом в консоль и считать эти данные в программе на Си.

Что-то вроде:

```
char buf[256];
start ("python foo.py", &buf);
```

Где buf - весь вывод скрипта.

Comment: В офф. документации, вроде, [есть примеры](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) этого. Смотрели? Или не помогло?

Comment: Вы не поняли, нужно запустить приложение из программы на Си и получить ее вывод, это не обязательно питоновский скрипт, может быть .bat файл или консольное приложение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Для Linux

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main()
> {
>   FILE * uname;
>   char os[80];
>   int lastchar;
>
>   uname = popen("uname -o", "r");
>   lastchar = fread(os, 1, 80, uname);
>   os[lastchar] = '\0';
>   printf("Your OS is %s", os);
>   pclose(uname);
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

[Ссылка на оригинал](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=31512&p=158044#post158044)

P.S. `uname -o` выводит название OS в Linux.

### Для Windows

Для Windows есть аналог `popen` :

```
FILE *_popen(const char *command,const char *mode);
```

**Параметры:**

*command* - исполняемая команда, *mode* - состояние возвращаемого выражения.

Значения *mode*:

> "r" - Вызывающий процесс может считывать стандартный вывод порожденной
>   команды с помощью возвращенного потока.
>
> "w" - Вызывающий процесс может записывать в стандартный ввод
>   порожденной команды с помощью возвращенного потока.
>
> "b" - Открыть в бинарном режиме.
>
> "t" - Открыть в текстовом режиме.

[Ссылка на офф. документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx)

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> int main( void )
> {
>
>    char   psBuffer[128];
>    FILE   *pPipe;
>
>    if( (pPipe = _popen( "dir *.c /on /p", "rt" )) == NULL )
>       exit( 1 );
>
>    /* Read pipe until end of file, or an error occurs. */
>
>    while(fgets(psBuffer, 128, pPipe))
>    {
>       printf(psBuffer);
>    }
>
>
>    /* Close pipe and print return value of pPipe. */
>    if (feof( pPipe))
>    {
>      printf( "\nProcess returned %d\n", _pclose( pPipe ) );
>    }
>    else
>    {
>      printf( "Error: Failed to read the pipe to the end.\n");
>    }
> }
> ```

К сожалению, нет возможности проверить код.

Comment: Хорошо, а в Винде что делать?

Comment: @Indev, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Answer (score 2):

В Unix Вашу проблему можно решить следующим образом:

1. cоздаем неименованный канал (вызов *Pipe()*);
2. порождаем дочерний процесс (вызов *fork()*);
3. если требуется передавать данные только от дочернего процесса (там
   мы запустим Ваш скрипт) в родительский (Ваша программа на С), то в
   родительском процессе оставляем открытым только дескриптор канала на
   чтение, закрываем на запись, в дочернем - наоборот, закрываем
   дескриптор канала на чтение, оставляем дескриптор на запись;
4. если хотим, чтобы в родительский процесс сыпались все сообщения(в
   том числе и об ошибках) из запущенной в дочернем процессе программы,
   перенаправляем все потоки вывода дочернего процесса в дескриптор
   канала на запись вызовом *dup2()*;
5. одним из вызовов семейства *exec()* (их много, посмотрите, какой Вам
   удобнее использовать) запускаем нужную вам программу/утилиту/скрипт
   в дочернем процессе, не забываем проверить, что *exec()* выполнился
   без ошибок, больше в коде дочернего процесса ничего не делаем.
6. в родительском процессе, из оставшегося незакрытым дескриптора
   неименованного канала читаем то, что выводит запущенный в дочернем
   процессе скрипт.

*Все нюансы относительно использования системных вызовов можно поискать в манах, или, например, посмотреть в книгах Стивенса.

Answer (score 2):

Внесу еще 5 копеек в варианты решения для Linux.

Используем [forkpty](http://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty) для получения канала  связи с запускаемой командой. Существенное отличие от предыдущих вариантов в том, что мы получаем двунаправленную "терминалоподобную" (**pty**)  связь. В принципе таким образом (ну, добавив кое-что в управление псевдотерминалом) можно моделировать реальный диалог с любой программой (например, vi(?)), хотя наиболее применимо для su/ssh и т.п., отказывающихся читать пароль не с терминала (но не только, потому что вообще-то, поведение FILE * зависит от того, работает он с терминалом или файлом, пайпом и т.п.).

Конечно, в рамках этого вопроса такие возможности избыточны, но все же ...

```
// compile gcc (or g++) with -lutil
// Запустим переданные аргументы командной строки, как команду
// и напечатаем ее stdout/stderr,
// а затем выведем результат ее работы (код возврата)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pty.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int tty;
  pid_t child = forkpty(&tty, 0, 0, 0);

  // в этой точке у нас работают (надеемся!) уже два процесса (один запущен внутри forkpty)
  // поэтому проявите особое внимание к вставке сюда какого-то кода

  switch (child) {
  case -1:
    err(EX_OSERR, "forkpty");  // never Returns
  case 0:
    // эта часть switch исполняется в "дочернем" процессе!!!
    // запустим команду, которая будет писать в наш tty
    execvp(av[1], &av[1]); // при успешном вызове возврата не будет
    err(EX_UNAVAILABLE, "execvp"); // never Returns
  }

  // а здесь уже наверняка опять один процесс (исходный "папа")

  char *str = 0;
  size_t ssz;
  FILE *in = fdopen(tty, "r"); // привяжем к tty FILE

  while (getline(&str, &ssz, in) != EOF) // getline() еще одна удобная GNU штучка
    fputs(str, stdout);

  fclose(in); // tty закроется здесь

  int s, rc;
  wait(&s);   // мы запускали один процесс и ждем его завершения, так что можно не изгаляться с waitpid/wait3 и т.п.
  // корректная обработка всех возможных ситуаций немного длинее, для простоты опустим их
  const char *msg = WIFEXITED(s) ? "exited with code" : "terminated by signal";
  rc = *msg == 'e' ? WEXITSTATUS(s) : WTERMSIG(s);
  printf("---- %s (%ld) %s %d ----\n",
         av[1], (long)child, msg, rc);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

А теперь запустим и посмотрим:

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ -Wall t.c -lutil ; ./a.out ls -alR /tmp
/tmp:
total 32
drwxrwxrwt  6 root    root    4096 Nov  2 13:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root    root    4096 Oct 20 15:07 ..
-rw-------  1 avp     avp        0 Oct 29 13:35 config-err-TwtmYo
drwx------  2 avp     avp     4096 Oct 29 13:36 .esd-1000
drwx------  2 lightdm lightdm 4096 Oct 29 13:36 .esd-104
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root    4096 Oct 29 13:35 .ICE-unix
-r--r--r--  1 root    root      11 Oct 29 13:34 .X0-lock
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root    4096 Oct 29 13:34 .X11-unix
-rw-------  1 avp     avp      418 Oct 29 13:35 .xfsm-ICE-NLCL7X

/tmp/.esd-1000:
total 8
drwx------ 2 avp  avp  4096 Oct 29 13:36 .
drwxrwxrwt 6 root root 4096 Nov  2 13:08 ..
srwxrwxrwx 1 avp  avp     0 Oct 29 13:36 socket
ls: cannot open directory /tmp/.esd-104: Permission denied

/tmp/.ICE-unix:
total 8
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 4096 Oct 29 13:35 .
drwxrwxrwt 6 root root 4096 Nov  2 13:08 ..
srwxrwxrwx 1 avp  avp     0 Oct 29 13:35 2019

/tmp/.X11-unix:
total 8
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 4096 Oct 29 13:34 .
drwxrwxrwt 6 root root 4096 Nov  2 13:08 ..
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Oct 29 13:34 X0
---- ls (14744) exited with code 2 ----
End
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ 
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out hjsdjhdj
a.out: execvp: No such file or directory
---- hjsdjhdj (14783) exited with code 69 ----
End
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```